# Method calling - Cocoa/Obj-C

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I'm learning Cocoa...
I tried different way to do that but I'm still in the black...

I have this method in my implementation:

```
- (void)closeStream:(NSStream *)theStream {

    [theStream close];
    [theStream removeFromRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];

}
```

How can I call it from an IBAction in my @synthetize?

```
    - (IBAction)connect:(id)sender {

        if ([[connectNOK stringValue] isEqualToString:@"Disconnected"]) {

            [connectButton setTitle:@"Disconnect"];   
            NSString * hostFromField = [hostField stringValue];

            CFReadStreamRef readStream;
            CFWriteStreamRef writeStream;
            CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(NULL, (CFStringRef)hostFromField, [portField intValue], &readStream, &writeStream);
            inputStream = (NSInputStream *)readStream;
            outputStream = (NSOutputStream *)writeStream;

            [inputStream setDelegate:self];
            [outputStream setDelegate:self];

            [inputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
            [outputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];

            [inputStream open];
            [outputStream open];

        } else {

            [connectButton setTitle:@"Connect"];

            // I want to call this method here   
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the `closeStream:` method is defined in the **same class** than the `connect:` method, you'll have to use:

```
[ self closeStream: someStream ];
```

Where `someStream` is the `NSStream` object you need to pass.

The **`self`** keyword refers to the **current instance** of the class.

If you don't know that, or what it means, I suggest you take a look at the **[Objective-C language basics](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/Learning_Objective-C_A_Primer/)** before trying to do/code anything, and maybe after, the [complete language reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Introduction/introObjectiveC.html).

**EDIT:**

I can see in your code that your `connect:` method «toggles» the connection based on the value of a button label.

This is not a very good design, for you to know, but you'll have other problems here.

I guess you want to close the input and output streams, if necessary.
The problem is, when the `connect` method is called a second time, the `inputStream` and `outputStream` variables are not accessible anymore, as they are [**local** variables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_variable).

You probably need to store them as [**instance** variables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instance_variable) instead, so you can refer to them later on.

Once again, it seems you really should start by reading some documentation about programming principles, as well as some Object-Oriented programming principles.
Don't try to go too fast. Knowledge is the key to everything, so start by reading the documentation I mentioned before.

Comment: That's the full language spec. For someone new, it'd be better to start with [Learning Objective-C: A Primer](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/Learning_Objective-C_A_Primer/).

Comment: You're perfectly right, thanks : ) Corrected my answer with your link as well.